# error illegal string offset in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am getting error illegal sting offset in variable 'slug' and 'judul' in my view. can you tell me what the probelm.

controller

```
function index()
{
    $slug = $this->uri->segment(2);
    $this->data['halaman'] = $this->mhalaman->get_profil($slug);

    if (empty($this->data['halaman'])) {
        show_404();
    }
    $this->data['judul'] = $this->data['halaman']['judul'];
    //var_dump($halaman_item['slug']);
    $this->data['orang'] = $this->mlogin->dataPengguna($this->session->userdata('username'));
    $this->data['contents'] = $this->load->view('page', $this->data, true);
    $this->load->view('template/wrapper/mahasiswa/wrapper_content',$this->data);
}
```

view

```
<div class="section ui dropdown link item">
                        <span class="count">Profil</span>
                        <div class="menu">

                            <?php foreach ($halaman as $dt) : ?>
                            <div class="item">
                              <a href="/tkd/index.php/page/<?php echo $dt['slug'] ?>"><?php echo $dt['judul'] ?></a> //line error
                            </div>

                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </div>
                      </div>
```

modal

```
function get_profil($slug = FALSE)
    {
        if ($slug === FALSE)
        {
            $query = $this->db->get($this->tbl_halaman);
            return $query->result_array();
        }

        $query = $this->db->get_where($this->tbl_halaman, array('slug'=>$slug));
        return $query->row_array();
    }
```

please help me what to do. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `echo $dt` instead of `echo $dt['slug']`

Comment: i has been try but error array to string conversion. how?

Comment: can you tell us what is the result of `print_r($this->data)` in controller before loading the view?

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [id_halaman] => 1 [id_admin] => [slug] => sejarah [judul] => sejarah [content] =>
grkjnrkgrgn